# Parse error in where. Haskell

Tags: haskell

i'm having an error in this piece of code

```
raices :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
raices a b c = [(-b+d)/t,(-b-d)/t]
    where d = sqrt (b^2 - 4*a*c)
          t = 2*a
```

This is the ERROR that ghci give to me

```
parse error on input ‘=’  
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?  
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
174|                   t = 2*a
   |                     ^
```

Thanks in advance StackOverflow programmers :D!

Comment: Did you mix up tabs and/or spaces? The posted function works fine, so my guess is that the indentation is incorrect.

Comment: Well as said, it compiles fine here. So you probably did not copy your function verbatim, or it has to do something with other code in the file.

Comment: Yeah, was that, i mix tabs and spaces, arrrrggg, Thank you very much! :)